# django read radio value from a normal form

Tags: html, django

my form code is :

```
<td class="desc"><label>Description:<input type="text" name="desc"></label></td>
    <td class="tags"><label>Tags:<input type="text" name="tag"></label></td>
<td><label>Public:<input type="radio" name="pri" value="1"></label>
<label>Private:<input type="radio" name="pri" value="0"></label></td>
```

in views.py

```
meta['pri'] = request.POST.get('pri','')
```

why i choose the Private button, the value "pri" always is the "1"

Comment: Everything looks fine...probably you are mistaken somewhere else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting by name, so the first element with the name 'pri' is selected, which will always be the label element with the name 'pri' and a value of 1. The name of the label should be different to the name of the input element.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get the result like this:

```
meta['pri'] = bool(request.POST.get('pri')=='1')
```

Answer (score 0):

Only solution for this is using onclick event on radio button and writing to hidden input with another name, then working with this input in views

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: 1 - I am OP
2 - Charl's answer not working, i need django to read value of checked radio button, as you know it MUST have similar names in html to work properly. But django always returning true or false for last radio button found with this name.